# I wanna know what this belongs too is it a part for a car or a boat or something else

Tags: part-identification

[image]

What kind of part is this and what does it do

Comment: Can that red thing be pushed? What does the rest of it look like? What do the ends of the wire look like? Is there any sort of label or model number at all? Where did you find it? Is that a lever which rocks back and forth?

Answer (score 4):

It's a vintage turn signal of the type used on semi-trucks.

[image]

(Taken from [this YouTube.com video](https://youtu.be/2rNz8-oWEUo))

Comment: It was used on cars also, back when you wanted to add turn signals to a car/pickup that did not have them from the factory or sometimes was cheaper than fixing the factory turn signal switch. Put many of them on myself.

Comment: @Moab - I had only seen them used on older semis, but absolutely I could see them being used anywhere like what you're talking about. Pretty much foolproof and worked, so there you go :o)

Comment: What is the red button for? Hazards?

Comment: Red button is 4 way hazard switch.  Also common on school buses from 1950's and early 1960's.

Comment: Turn signals and dual brake lamps wasn't required by law in the USA until 1960.